# masking array with logical values along an arbitrary axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a multidimensional array and a vector of logical values. I want to select items along an arbitrary (n-th) dimension. In the following example I am going to select the first and third values along the second dimension:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> mask = np.array([True, False, True, False])
>>> dim_to_mask = 1  # i.e. 2nd dimension because it's 0-indexed
>>> B = ... # here do mask the dim_to_mask-th dimension - HOW???
>>> B
[[1, 3], 
 [5, 7], 
 [9, 11]]
```

Note: assume that the length of the logical vector corresponds to the length of the given axis.

I know it would be easy if the array is just one-dimensional using `[]` operator, but this is multidimensional problem.

Actually I want something like function `take(indices, axis)` which selects given indices along an arbitrary axis. The only difference is that I do have logical values instead of numeric indices.

I am also aiming at the fastest solution so converting vector of logical values to indices and using `take` is probably not the best solution.

I guess it must be something obvious which I am missing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.compress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress):

```
>>> A.compress(mask, axis=1)
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

This function returns slices of an array along a particular axis. It accepts a boolean array with which to make the selections.